# Returning a filtered summary in a function in dplyr/R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of male and female names. Using dplyr, I have created a list of names that are common to both sexes in a function. I'm able to return that list in the function. However, if I want to also show how many times each name in the list appears, how do I return that as a dataframe?

Suppose I have the final list of names as

```
x <- intersect(boys, girls)
```

where boys and girls are separate lists of names.

How do I also add the number of times each name appears? I tried-

```
x <- intersect(boys, girls)
return(tabulate(x))
```

This doesn't work though.

Comment: Please include some sample data to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: maybe like table(x)

Comment: actually i made a mistake in the first section while using the intersect() which is why the table or count won't work anymore. I will need to think of other ways

Answer (score 0):

```
table(x)
```

Or,

```
x %>% data.frame(common_names = x) %>% count(common_names)
```